# Combine RGB channels from separate images using ImageMagick

Tags: cmd, command-line, imagemagick

I'm trying to combine the RGB channels from 3 separate images using ImageMagick. The red channel from image01.png, blue channel from image02.png and the green channel from image03.png

*Image01.png, Image02.png, Image03.png*

[image]
[image]
[image]

The resulting image **should** look like this (left) but I'm getting this (right):

[image]
[image]

This is the command I'm running....

```
"C:/ImageMagick/magick.exe" convert "C:/images/image01.png" "C:/images/image02.png" "C:/images/image03.png" "-background" "#ff0000" "-channel" "red,green,blue" "-combine" "C:/images/combined.png"
```

Do I need to somehow save out the various channels of each image separating first and then combine the images?

Comment: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` has a different syntax than the Linux shell interpreters. So first replace all `'` by `"` because of `'` has no special meaning for `cmd.exe` in comparison to Linux shell interpreters. Second the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux and for that reason replace all `/` by ``\`` in the command line. CMD interprets `,` as argument separator and replaces it by a space character, except the comma is inside an argument string enclosed in `"`. Therefore `'red,green,blue'` is something completely different than `"red,green,blue"`.

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, -channel does not work to select channels from multiple images.

Furthermore and more importantly, white contains red, green and blue. So the red channel of the first image will have the red dot as white and the background white as white, leaving black for the green and blue lines. Similarly in the other images. So white needs to be made black in each image. Then the channels are separated and recombined. Then black needs to be made white again.

Unix syntax:

```
convert \
\( image01.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white \
-channel r -separate +channel \) \
\( image02.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white \
-channel g -separate +channel \) \
\( image03.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white \
-channel b -separate +channel \) \
-set colorspace sRGB -combine \
-fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque black \
result.png
```

Windows Syntax:

```
convert.exe ^
( image01.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white ^
-channel r -separate +channel ) ^
( image02.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white ^
-channel g -separate +channel ) ^
( image03.png -fuzz 70% -fill black -opaque white ^
-channel b -separate +channel ) ^
-set colorspace sRGB -combine ^
-fuzz 20% -fill white -opaque black ^
result.png
```

[image]

The -fuzz is needed to remove the anti-aliased colors that are near white around the edges of the colored regions.

You would be much better starting with the 3 input images that have a black background rather than white. Then all the fuzz and white to black and black back to white would not be needed.

Comment: I should have mentioned it appears white but the background is transparent :)

Comment: The images that you posted when download are not transparent. They have a white background. Can you upload images that actually will have transparency when download?

Comment: I can upload the original source images which have transparent backgrounds.