# Combining tiff files by channel with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, tiff

I am trying to combine three channel-based TIFF files into a single RGB one. The individual files look like this (this one is red): [image: red channel example]

Based on [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62926021/221814), I tried this command to merge them:

```
convert \
\( ./raw/red.TIF -channel r -separate +channel \) \
\( ./raw/green.TIF -channel g -separate +channel \) \
\( ./raw/blue.TIF -channel b -separate +channel \) \
-set colorspace sRGB -combine \
./test.tif
```

However, instead of a nice full-colour image, what I get instead is:
[image: bad combined file] (you can just make out the tiny, incorrectly combined image in the top left corner).

What is it I'm doing wrong here?

---

EDIT: You can get these TIFF files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iiqa7877kjwd67h/AABJ79jSilNOFTHqfuo-LefEa?dl=0). (These are Landsat images.)

Comment: Can you share the actual TIFFs please rather than JPEG versions? Maybe use Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch as imgur doesn't support such things.

Comment: It is possible that you have a multi-page TIFF-file.
And his first page is low-resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a dropbox link to the TIFFs.

Answer (score 1):

Your TIFFs are *pyramidal*, or multi-resolution. You can see that with this command to look at the individual images in the blue TIFF:

```
magick identify LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[0] TIFF 7591x7731 7591x7731+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 83.8667MiB 0.010u 0:00.006
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[1] TIFF 3796x3866 3796x3866+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.010u 0:00.001
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[2] TIFF 1898x1933 1898x1933+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.010u 0:00.001
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[3] TIFF 949x967 949x967+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.010u 0:00.000
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[4] TIFF 475x484 475x484+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.010u 0:00.000
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[5] TIFF 238x242 238x242+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[6] TIFF 119x121 119x121+0+0 16-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
```

To make the full-size RGB render you need to take the zero-index (highest resolution) image by using the sub-image number in square brackets after the filename:

```
magick LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_red.TIF[0]   \
       LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_green.TIF[0] \
       LC08_L2SP_039035_20210708_20210713_02_T1_blue.TIF[0]  \
       -combine result.tif
```

[image]